# Printing inline style values of an HTML element using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How can i print the value of style attribute of an html element using javascript. I can get a specific style property value using `document.getElementById('myId').style.property`, where `property` is something like `width`, `height` etc.

However, how can I get the entire list of styles for an element?

Comment: If you want the value of an element's style **attribute** (i.e. the "inline" style) then the only way is *getAttribute* (which is buggy in some browsers so not very reliable). However, if you want values of the various **properties** of an HTML element's style object, the answers below might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('myId').style.cssText` as a String, or `document.getElementById('myId').style` as an Object.

Edit:

As far as I can tell, this returns the "actual", inline style. On the element `<a id='myId' style='font-size:inherit;'>`, `document.getElementById('myId').style.cssText` should return `"font-size:inherit;"`. If that is not what you want, try `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle` or `document.getElementById('myId').currentStyle` (the first one is all except IE, the second one is IE only). See [here](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/) for more on computed vs. cascaded styles.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="x" style="font-size:15px">a</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStyle(oElm, strCssRule){
    var strValue = "";
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
        strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
    }
    else if(oElm.currentStyle){
        strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){
            return p1.toUpperCase();
        });
        strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
    }
    return strValue;
}

// get what style rule you want
alert(getStyle(document.getElementById('x'), 'font-size'));
</script>
```

Comment: Is document.defaultView supported in IE 9

Answer (score 2):

Oh  srsly... it's as easy as

```
element.style.cssText
```

and it's [cross browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t30)

http://jsfiddle.net/4F2RQ/

Answer (score 1):

This should do a dump of the object:
Here's an [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4EBk9/)

EDIT: Its a little weird:

```
for (var prop in styles) {
    console.log(styles[prop], styles[styles[prop]]);
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing; but unfortunately, that does not work.