# Fetch value from scss file

Tags: html, sass

I have an scss file with some colour codes set in variables like $base-colour:#fff444. I need to retrieve those  colour values to a column of a html table.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: POST code also.

Comment: I think what you are looking for can be found here, can be done easily with JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7326192/4548398

Comment: code in colour.scc : $basecolor : #fff444 ,     code in html page : <table border ="1"><tr><td bgcolor ="filepath of .scss/$basecolor"></td></tr></table>      I need to know how can we access the variable value of basecolor(ie: #fff444) of scss file in html page. I am new to scss

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a variable from a .scss file directly in html. You have to use a css selector in your .scss file to style the table. For example you could do something like this:

```
table td{
    background-color: $base-colour;
}
```

However, I would recommend giving your table a class and styling it using that.